# How would one add two lists in this way in Python?

Tags: python

Say if

```
list1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape']
list2 = ['pineapple', 'banana', 'pear']
```

how could you add them so that

```
list3 = ['apple pineapple', 'orange banana', 'grape pear']
```

Using a for statement inside a for statement I can get this out:

```
applepineapple
applebanana
applepear
orangepineapple
orangebanana
orangepear
grapepineapple
grapebanana
grapepear
```

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use nested loops, just use a single loop that accesses the `i`th element of both lists.

Comment: What happened to "grape" in the third list, and where did "oranges" come from?

Comment: Me being silly. Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> list1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape'] 
>>> list2 = ['pineapple', 'banana', 'pear']
>>> [ list1[x]+ " " +list2[x] for x in range(len(list1))]   # both should must have same length
['apple pineapple', 'orange banana', 'grape pear']
```

pythonic way:

```
>>> map(" ".join,zip(list1,list2))
['apple pineapple', 'orange banana', 'grape pear']
```

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to do this. One way is a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
>>> zip(list1, list2)
[('apple', 'pineapple'), ('orange', 'banana'), ('grape', 'pear')]
>>> ['{} {}'.format(x, y) for x, y in zip(list1, list2)]
['apple pineapple', 'orange banana', 'grape pear']
```

You can also use concatenation (`x + ' ' + y`) or interpolation (`'%s %s' % (x, y)`) to form the strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
print ([' '.join(z) for z in zip(list1,list2)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line with:

> > > new_list = map(lambda x : x[0]+' '+x[1], zip(list1, list2))

zip() takes two sequences and forms list where the i-th entry is a tuple containing the i-th entry of the first list and the i-th entry of the second list.  map(func, sequence) applies a given function to a sequence.  These two commands will save you a ton of time working with lists.